# Python - Dynamic Function - RecursionError, trouble in understanding

Tags: python, function, dynamic, task

I'm having a problem with a given task we've got in school. The following recursive function is to be defined in python:

```
M(n+3) = M(n) - M(n+1) + 2*M(n+2)
```

for testing the following results these testcases should return and the function is to be called within the range of 0 to 9:

```
M(0) = 0, M(1)=3, M(2)=2
```

i've tried the following:

```
def M(n):
    x = n + 3
    return M(x) - M(x+1) + 2 * M(x+2)


for i in range(0, 9):
    print(M(i))
```

however, when called, the max number of recursions is reached and an error is given out. Idk if im just too stupid and missing something here but nobody in my class has been able to solve this problem and my teachers pretty busy today, so i hope i can find some help in here.

Comment: First, you need to define the return values for n=0, 1, 2 separately (otherwise the function would called with negative values infinitely small).  Also, you have a bug in the code defining `x`.  Rewrite the original equation as: `M(n) = M(n-3) - M(n-2) + 2*M(n-1)`.   This should be more straightforward to turn into a program.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i'm understanding it now!

Answer (score 0):

Convert this

```
M(n+3) = M(n) - M(n+1) + 2*M(n+2)
```

to

```
M(n)=M(n-3)-M(n-2)+ 2*M(n-1)
```

- Both are of same meaning
- **Also you have to define base cases**

So this will be your Python code

```py
def M(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    elif n==1:
        return 3
    elif n==2:
        return 2
    else:
        return M(n-3) - M(n-2) + 2 * M(n-1)

for i in range(0, 9):
    print(M(i))
```

Hope this solves your issue

Comment: Ahh, i see. Yeah now that i see it i dont really know how i couldn'tve come up with that.. Thanks very much!